# Doubt regarding 'edits'

Tags: discussion, moderation

So I have privileges to approve and reject edits. I have seen new users tend to provide some background about either their knowledge/previous work (in a very layman way). For example : " So I am a beginner in AI and I do not have much understanding of calculus and so ......Actual question......".

Now some users want to remove this introductory part. My question is what are the general rules in this case? Should the intro be removed? Or does it serve some purpose in answering a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question becomes whether that information and the context it provides might be relevant in understanding the source of confusion or how the question might be answered (i.e. write for your audience).

Certainly, someone saying:

> "I am an {x} year student who is/is not familar with {x}; can you explain this to me in a way that others like me will understand?"* ← *USEFUL CONTEXT*

Of course, that doesn't necessarily forgive a question exhibiting insufficient understanding of the problem to bring it to a site like this ("too soon, where are you  stuck specifically? what have you tried?").

But where "needless introductions" can be stripped away is where it becomes chatty filler not really relevant to the post:

> "Hi, guys. I love this site and y'all are great and I've been here for 3 years and now I have a question and I hope you all can help me yada yada ...
>
> <actual question>
>
> Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. Important, important. Hopefully I can get an answer soon.
>
> signed <username> <smiley emoji>
> <list of credentials>
> <list of favorite tomes>
> <meme cartoon>

Of course, you don't have to become overly head-strong and vigilant in stripping away *every* incidental nicety. The overall goal is to make the content *demonstrably* more clear for those who come after. Use your judgement with those goals in mind and most of those leave-it/remove-it questions should become a bit more self-evident.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.